# OpenLayers - different style on overviewmap

Tags: openlayers

I'm looking to use a different style on the [overview map](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_OverviewMap-OverviewMap.html) from the main map area.  I have some text/SVGs showing up on the main map that are way too big for the overview map. Ideally, I would like to have a simple point on the overview map with no text.

I've considered using an if statement in the style function and returning a different style if the resolution is greater than N however, at some point each map will get the wrong style.

[image: openlayers with cluttered overview map]

Comment: Use the layers option on the overview map to use its own layer (same source as main map, but with  style function appropriate for overview).

Comment: that worked.  If you want to answer the question and add a little more context, I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the OverviewMap `layers` option to explicitly specify the layers to be used there.  Vector layers can then be defined to display the source used in the main map with styling specific to the overview.

Incidentally in OpenLayers 6 that will be mandatory for any OverviewMap https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#the-overviewmap-requires-a-list-of-layers